Extensions of algebraic groups and extensions of fpqc sheaves
There are at least two ways to define $\operatorname{Ext}^p(F,G)$ when $F$ and $G$ are commutative algebraic groups over a field $k$:

Pass to the associated fppf sheaves and use an injective resolution of $G$.
Work in the category of commutative pro-algebraic groups over $k$, which is abelian and has enough projectives, and take a projective resolution of $F$.

In other words, one can study Yoneda extensions of fppf sheaves or Yoneda extensions of pro-algebraic groups.  When $p=1$, these definitions agree because the underlying fppf sheaf of an extension of $G$ by $F$ is an algebraic space with a group structure, hence an algebraic group.
What is the relationship between the two definitions for $p > 1$?

To talk about Yoneda extensions, you don't need resolutions and you don't need to have an abelian category. So I believe that the comparison that you want is between extensions of fppf sheaves (computed as derived functors) and extensions of commutative algebraic groups (defined as Yoneda extensions). The former coincides with the Yoneda extensions of fppf sheaves as well, so there's a natural map from the Ext^p of algebraic groups to the Ext^p of fppf sheaves. It's not usually an isomorphism for p>1, and I don't believe that there's much more to say about it.

The Yoneda Ext does not in general agree with the derived functor of Hom on fppf sheaves. In "On a nontrivial higher extension of representable abelian sheaves" by L. Breen, it is shown by hand that for a characteristic 2 field $k$, $Ext^2_{fppf}(\alpha_2,\mathbb{G}_m) \neq 0$, while if $k = \bar{k}$, the corresponding Yoneda Ext group vanishes.
You may be interested in Akhil Mathew's recent talk "Multiplicative Polynomial Laws and Commutative Group Schemes" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YF9tnUya-Q. The talk suggests replacing $Ext^*_{fppf}$ by the extension groups in the category of multiplicative polynomial laws, which is smaller than $Ext^*_{fppf}$ but still admits a map from the Yoneda Ext groups. For example, it is stated in Akhil's talk that $Ext_{mult. pol.}^*(G,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is zero for finite $G$ when $\ast > 1$.
